# iphone sticky menu jquery onscroll ios 9

Tags: css, webkit, css-position, ios9, fixed

This code was working fine on my iphone before updating to **iOS 9.0.1** (13A404),
 but now the same code seems to be working only after finger release,
 or after the jQuery `onscroll` ends, when I do a quick swipe leaving the page scrolling...

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0){
        $('.menu').addClass('sticky');
    }else{
        $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

The sticky menu just disappears until I release the finger up from the screen, losing the "stickying" effect in realtime during the swipe that I had before in all my websites and that are now broken...

How can solve this problem making them working like I had before? (smooth sticky in realtime)

Comment: Why element cant have sticky class from the beginning?

Comment: @IonDen I already tried to set a fixed position from the beginning, but I cannot figure out how to do in case I have the sticky menu between other elements e.g. after an header on top of the page

Comment: @neoDev The new version of iOS may be "improving" the user experience by showing a static image of the webpage during swipe. You could test this by creating a page with a simple marquee.

Comment: @Popnoodles Yes I already created a very simple page to make tests

Comment: And does the animation pause on swipe/scroll or continue to animate?

Comment: @Popnoodles what animation?

Comment: You need to test whether or not the hypothesis that iOS 9.0.1 (13A404) uses a screenshot version of the webpage while scrolling/swiping is true, which you can do by creating a page with a marquee or other simple animation and see if it freezes while scrolling/swiping.

Answer (score 9):

After observing the same behaviour and testing around a bit, the simplest way is to activate 3D transforms [as proposed in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875046/ios-9-safari-changing-an-element-to-fixed-position-while-scrolling-wont-paint#answer-32891079):

```
.sticky-element {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
}
```

Comment: GREAT! this fixed the issue I had with the StickyJS plugin on my iPhone6. It only snapped into place once scrolling stopped - but after adding this bit of css to the class/element I want to stick; it was working. I haven't got an Android to test on but happy as long as it works on iPhone.

Comment: The problems with changed rendering behaviour on the client is that no lib can predict this case and all solutions break at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same behavior. It seems iOS9 doesn't want to paint position: fixed elements until AFTER a scroll event has ended.

Example: http://senaeh.de/demo/stickyheaders/simple/

The new sticky header will not show until either the page stops scrolling or the user removes their finger from the screen. Other CSS changes such as background-color work as they should.

This is a regression since iOS8 allowed this completely. Sticky headers are unfortunately not smooth as of ios9.0.1. They still work great on aging Android devices so I'm not sure if this is a bug or if Apple is trying to increase battery life.

EDIT: I filed a bug with Apple (#22902083) so let's hope they make an update to remedy this.

Comment: Observing exactly the same behaviour here.