# Followup on: iOS 9 Safari: changing an element to fixed position while scrolling won't paint until scroll stops

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ios9

I've run into the same issue that Pablo describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875046/ios-9-safari-changing-an-element-to-fixed-position-while-scrolling-wont-paint).

> if the position of an element changes from static/relative/absolute to fixed while the scroll animation is ongoing the element becomes invisible until after the scroll has come to a stop.

The 3D transform trick described in that thread worked for me with Safari and Firefox but I still see the behavior described above in Chrome and Opera Mini.

Any thoughts on a fix, workaround, hack, etc. for those two?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see that issue in Chrome ([this demo](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/)), and why are you testing Opera Mini? It [doesn't support hardly anything](http://caniuse.com/#compare=op_mini+5.0-8.0)

Comment: I'm seeing inconsistent behavior with Chrome using that demo page. There are times where I'll load it and if I do the scroll with my finger on the sidebar, it works, but then if I scroll again with my finger in the middle content, it doesn't.  Then it will all of a sudden just start working. Odd. Also, Opera Mini is just another data point - I check that when I see something weird.