# jquery script works on desktop, but lags on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

I tried to implement a div on my website, that sticks to the top of the browser as soon as it scrolls out of the viewport. I found a script that does this pretty good and it works well on the desktop. When I test it on the iphone I have a short lag where the div scrolls out for about a half second and pop then up at the desired location. Has anybody a clue how I could tweak that script?

Here is the link: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/)

Thanks for your help!

```
function sticky_relocate() {
            var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
            var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
            if (window_top > div_top) {
                $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
                $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
            } else {
                $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
                $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
            }
        }

        $(function() {
            $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
            sticky_relocate();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `setTimeout` and clear the interval when the scroll is invoked multiple times. This might help by limiting the number of times the callback is invoked.

```
$(function() {
  var timer;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      sticky_relocate();
    }, 50);
  });
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

Comment: thx for the reply. no change. I tried it with another script (http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/#reference) and there seems to be the same problem.

Comment: duh... found it. sorry.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828973/iphone-sticky-menu-jquery-onscroll-ios-9